# Only One EA works at a time. The others won't open as long as there's a trade

Tags: mql4

The Orderselect is used to control the number of trades the EA opens. I didnt use OrdersTotal because it creates the problem of blocking other EAs. Now it seems OrdersSelect also does the same thing. I need each EA to only open two trades and allow other EAs to open theirs too.

```
  void OnTick()
    {
       double movingAverageSS = iMA(NULL,60,LowerMAS,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);    
       double lastmovingAverageSS = iMA(NULL,60,LowerMAS,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,1);     
       double movingAverageSB = iMA(NULL,60,LowerMAB,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);       
       double lastmovingAverageSB = iMA(NULL,60,LowerMAB,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,1);          
       double movingAverageFS = iMA(NULL,60,UpperMAS,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);    
       double lastmovingAverageFS = iMA(NULL,60,UpperMAS,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,1);   
       double movingAverageFB = iMA(NULL,60,UpperMAB,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);    
       double lastmovingAverageFB = iMA(NULL,60,UpperMAB,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,1);    
    for(int b=0;b<OrdersTotal();b++)
   {
    if (OrderSelect(b,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES) == true)
      { 
      if (OrderMagicNumber() != MagicB)
        {
        if((lastmovingAverageFB<lastmovingAverageSB) && (movingAverageFB > movingAverageSB)) 
          {
           b = OrderSend (Symbol(),OP_BUY,lotSize,Ask,4,Ask - SLPB*_Point, Ask + TPB1*_Point,NULL,128,0,Green);
           b = OrderSend (Symbol(),OP_BUY,lotSize,Ask,4,Ask - SLPB*_Point, Ask + TPB2*_Point,NULL,128,0,Green);
          }
         else if((lastmovingAverageFS>lastmovingAverageSS)&&(movingAverageFS<movingAverageSS))
        {
           b = OrderSend (Symbol(),OP_SELL,lotSize,Bid,4,Ask + SLPS*_Point,Ask - TPS1*_Point,NULL,128,0,Red);
           b = OrderSend (Symbol(),OP_SELL,lotSize,Bid,4,Ask + SLPS*_Point,Ask - TPS2*_Point,NULL,128,0,Red);      
        } 
        }
       }   
    }
```

Comment: Use loop over `OrdersTotal()` selecting `OrderSelect()` and then `OrderMagicNumber()` to count for trades opened by specific magic number (input parameter, pass it in `OrderSend()` function when opening a trade.

Comment: I modified the code to try put in what you suggested. My logic is if it checks all the orders and can't find the specific magic number which I inputted (128) then it should open a new trade. I'm not sure why its not working

Comment: create a new function. the goal of that function is to check / count trades opened with some magic. then call the function in the `OnTick()`